# Python random number generation varying for the same seed

Tags: python, python-3.x, montecarlo, random-seed

I am writing some Monte Carlo code (Python 3.7) and I am unable to find out why I get different results with the same random seed.

I have narrowed down to the function at which I start getting variations in the random results for the same seed. I create an instance of rng = random.Random() to make sure the other imports are not interfering with the random.seed. I have also tested a sequence of random numbers with the imports I use (only third-party is numpy) and this does not seem to be the issue either. My code is not multi-threaded either.

I setup my rng by:

```py
rng = random.Random()
rng.seed(123)
```

The variations are starting here at this function (also there seems to be a pattern to the variation it can be consistent for some runs and then vary for some runs - back and forth):

```py
def create_self_avoiding_walk(radii, origin, rng, max_iterations=10000):
    assert len(radii) > 0
    previous_radii = radii[0]
    previous_coords = origin
    new_coord_map = np.zeros((len(radii), 3))
    new_coord_map[0] = origin
    for i, radius in enumerate(radii):
        if i == 0:
            continue
        r = radius + previous_radii
        for iteration in range(0, max_iterations):
            theta = rng.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
            z = rng.uniform(-r, r)
            x = np.sqrt((r ** 2 - z ** 2)) * np.cos(theta)
            y = np.sqrt((r ** 2 - z ** 2)) * np.sin(theta)

            x += previous_coords[0]
            y += previous_coords[1]
            z += previous_coords[2]

            proposed_coords = [x, y, z]

            if coordinate_clash(np.array(proposed_coords), np.array(new_coord_map[:i]), radius, radii[:i]) is False:
                new_coord_map[i] = [x, y, z]
                previous_coords = [x, y, z]
                break
            if iteration == max_iterations - 1:  # Was unable to find non-clashing structure
                return np.array([])
    return new_coord_map
```

coordinate_clash calls the following functions:

```py
@overload(np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, float, float)
def coordinate_clash(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, radius1, radius2):
    return ((x1 - x2) ** 2) + ((y1 - y2) ** 2) + ((z1 - z2) ** 2) < (
                (radius1 + radius2) ** 2) - 1e-15  # Float PRECISION


@overload(np.ndarray, np.ndarray, float, float)
def coordinate_clash(vec1, vec2, radius1, radius2):
    return coordinate_clash(vec1[0], vec1[1], vec1[2], vec2[0], vec2[1], vec2[2], radius1, radius2)


@overload(np.ndarray, np.ndarray, float, list)
def coordinate_clash(vec1, mat, radius1, radii):
    for row, radius_entry in zip(mat, radii):
        if coordinate_clash(vec1, row, radius1, radius_entry):
            return True
    return False
```

Can anyone identify anything in the above code that would cause the random sequence to become inconsistent for the same seed?

Comment: Can you show us the code that creates rng and passes it into the function? Besides that, the only thing I can think of is that there might be values of `r` for which the line `z = rng.uniform(-r, r)` will consume more or fewer bytes of random data from the rng. Small variations in `r` varying from run to run could in turn be explained by floating point inaccuracies that can be caused by modern FPUs using more bits of precision than your code sees. I'd add some debugging lines using https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.getstate to see exactly when the RNG goes 'out of sync'.

Comment: You mentioned `random.seed` - maybe that wasn't meant literally, but that has no effect on the `Random` instance you created.  You'd need to use `rng.seed()` to set its seed.

Comment: Sorry, for clarity I have edited the question. I do use ```rng.seed(123)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now solved this issue. I was looking in the wrong place. My random instance was working as it should be. However, where I read and parsed the dataset was being parsed in different orders, which resulted in the fluctuations seen in the random number generation. The culprit was running looping over `set(data)` to set up my data storage. It appears that `set()` does not enforce the order so it would change on different runs. Therefore, this can straightforwardly be solved using `sorted(set(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set then random seed, like below:

```
for iteration in range(0, max_iterations):
    rng.seed(0)  # an fixed number
    theta = rng.uniform(0, 2 * np.pi)
    z = rng.uniform(-r, r)
```

and when you want to generate new random digits, you should use that fixed number for every time.

Comment: This would result in the same theta and z for every loop though. We are using random here to attempt different theta and z then the algorithm fails to find a suitable coordinate.